# Hotkey to simulate model in dymola

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys, modelica, simulate, dymola

I'm using Dymola and have a difficult time finding a way to use a hotkey to simulate my current model.

I tried it with AutoHotkey with no result since I don't know how to use it when I have to click something in a program.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hotkey to simulate is <kbd>F10</kbd> and <kbd>F8</kbd> to check code.

Best regards,
Rene Just Nielsen

Comment: Wow.. that was so easy it's a little bit embarrassing.

Comment: You can find the full list of keyboard shortcuts in section 2.8 in "Dymola User Manual Volume 1" which can be found in the menu "Help" --> "Documentation" in Dymola.

Comment: Also related: http://www.claytex.com/blog/useful-keyboard-shortcuts-and-commands/